# React (react-native) / Redux - How to filter data coming from redux store?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux

Im trying to accomplish the following: I want to show data, then filter it / showing filtered results.
Im new to redux and have been reading a lot, I saw that its quite common to use the library reselect, but as I only need the filter option in one place, I didnt do that. I tried to implement what I read but somehow its not really working. Also Im not sure if the best way to do it would be inside action or inside mapStateToProps as I did (I read that data shouldnt be mutated inside reducer in case it would be needed somewhere else so thats why I tried to do it inside mapStateToProps). If anyone would have a look at my code and tell me what I am doing wrong, it would be great! Thanks!

The error Im getting is 'cannot read property filter of null, even though "state.allData.data" is an array of objects so I dont understand it..also Im not sure at all about the rest.

Ps. Sorry for so much code to read, but I tried to remove unnecessary parts

Action:

```
import axios from "axios";
import {FETCHING_DATA, FETCH_DATA_SUCESS, FETCH__DATA_ERR, FILTER__DATA} from "...";

export const FetchData = () => {
        return dispatch => {
            dispatch({type: FETCHING_DATA})

            return axios.get("https://example.com")
                .then(res => {
                    dispatch({type: FETCH_DATA_SUCESS, payload: res.data})
                })
                .catch(err => {
                    dispatch({type: FETCH_DATA_ERR, payload: err.data})
                })
        }
    },
    receiveSearchInput = (input) => {
        return dispatch => {
            dispatch({type: FILTER_DATA, input: input})
        }
    }
```

Reducer:

```
import {FETCHING_DATA, FETCH_DATA_SUCESS, FETCH_DATA_ERR, FILTER_DATA} from "...";

const initialState = {
    isFetching: null,
    data: [],
    hasError: false,
    errorMsg: null,
    seachInput: ""
}

export default function (state = initialState, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case FETCHING_DATA:
            return {
                ...state, isFetching: true, data: null, hasError: false, errorMsg: null
            }
        case FETCH_DATA_SUCESS:
            return {
                ...state, isFetching: false, data: action.payload, hasError: false, errorMsg: null
            }
        case FETCH_DATA_ERR:
            return {
                ...state, isFetching: false, data: action.payload, haserror: true, errorMsg: action.err
            }
        case FILTER_DATA:
            return {
                ...state,
                seachInput: action.input
            }
        default:
            return state;
    }
}

index.js for reducer:

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    allData: DataReducer
});

Container:

import React from "react";
import {connect} from "react-redux";
import {FetchCoinData, receiveSearchInput} from "..";
import { SearchBar } from 'react-native-elements'


class ItemContainer extends React.Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.FetchData()
    }

    filterData = (e) => {
        this.props.receiveSearchInput(e)
    }

    renderItems() {
        return this.props.allData.data.map((item, index) =>
            <Item
                key={index}
                name={item.name}
                symbol={item.symbol}
                price={item.price}
            />
        )        
    }
    render () {
        if (this.props.allData.isFetching) {
            return (
                <View>
                     ...
                </View>
            )
        }
        return (
            <View>
                <SearchBar
                    onChangeText={this.filterData}
                />
                    {this.renderItems()}
            </View>
        )
    }    
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        allData: state.allData,
        filteredItems: state.allData.data.filter((item) => item.symbol.toLowerCase().includes(state.allData.seachInput) || item.name.toLowerCase().includes(state.allData.seachInput))
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { FetchData, receiveSearchInput })(ItemContainer)
```

Comment: You dont have a reducer for `FETCHING_DATA`, in the action

Comment: Assuming that FECHTING_DATA is FETCHING_COIN_DATA, that reducers is setting your data to null, making your mapStateToProps crash. If you want to reset it, set it to []

Comment: Sorry!! that sort of typo was only on here, not in my actual code so that is not the problem. I edited my question.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming here that FECHTING_DATA is FETCHING_COIN_DATA in your reducers file.

What is happening is when you call `dispatch({type: FETCHING_DATA})`, that reducer sets the data to `null`, changing your props and re-rendering the component. When that happens, redux calls your `mapStateToProps` method, in which time `allData.data` is `null`, giving your the error. To avoid this behavior you should set `data: []`.

About where to filter your data. The problem with mapStateToProps is that is called whenever there is a change in that component's props. So if you have a more complex component with many different props mapped to it, you would be re-filtering your list many times even though the filter parameters might not had have changed. If it's a big list this could cause some lag in you application.

The way I do it is to use the `componentWillReceiveProps` lifecycle method and check if the filter has changed and them store the filtered list in the state.

```
componentWIllMount(nextProps) {
  if(this.props.allData.searchInput != nextProps.allData.searchInput  ||  // check if input has changed
    this.props.allData.data != nextProps.allData.data) { // check if data has changed

    // filter your data
    // ...
    this.setState({ filteredData })

}

// And change your renderItems method to
renderItems() {
  return this.state.filteredData.map(() => { /* ... */ });
}
```

Hope that helped!

Comment: Thank you. It makes sense now why it wasnt working. So before I started trying using redux for filtering, I actually did that with setState. I received my data from my reducer, rendered it, stored same data in my component state and onChange re-rendered it. Everything worked fine but while researching how to use redux properly, I would read a lot about how you shouldnt store data in your comp. state if that same component receives data from redux store and it actually makes sense, like that I wouldnt need to use redux at all if I have state in my container, thats why I removed it..